# enableAggregatingTask conflicts with productFlavors

Tags: gradle, dagger-hilt

I have to run :app:depencencies for update lock file which  is a kind of  mechanism to manage version.  But an error happens.  I think it's a bug.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dependencies'.
> Cannot change dependencies of dependency configuration ':app:standardDebugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath' after it has been included in dependency resolution. Use 'defaultDependencies' instead of 'beforeResolve' to specify default dependencies for a configuration.
```

When I remove a flavor starting with alphabet bigger than g, it works well.

Anyone  has as solution?
Thanks